# How to detect empty table when selecting a row in a jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Giving a simple table like this

```
<table id="exampleTable" class="table hover nowrap">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
   </thead></table>
```

Also, using the [jQuery Datatable plugin](https://datatables.net) and making the rows selectable, like in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html). The Javascript goes like this:

```
var exampleTable = $("#exampleTable").DataTable(
                    {
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "lengthChange": false,
                        "bPaginate": false
                    });

$('#exampleTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            $('#exampleTable tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );
```

So, when the table is empty, it shows a selectable row which says something like:

> No data available in table

How to detect the table is empty and not allow selection on that kind of "message rows"?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4h48og8/1/) with the code.

Comment: do you want hide table when there is no data?

Comment: But what happen then when I have only one row? @Murali no, I want to disable the selection on the "No data" row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check if there is td with the class dataTables_empty like this:

```
$('#exampleTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else if(! $(this).find('td.dataTables_empty').length){
            $('#exampleTable').DataTable().rows().nodes().each(function(){
               $(this).removeClass('selected');
            });
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in this possibility, but I was hoping to find a "cleaner" way to do it.

Comment: looks clean enough for me :), I don't know how else you would check if there are entries? Maybe Datatable provides some callback functions where you can check it

Comment: That was exacly what I was hoping for :)

Comment: I have updated your answer, cause it is necessary to remove the `selected` class  from the hidden rows too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the - `.row().data()` method to see if there is data. if this returns undefined, you can disable selection of the row.

i also think this would be an ideal solution instead of dom traversal which is more expensive. what do you guys think ?

below is the updated fiddle. you can comment the tbody from the html to test it.

Let me know if this helps.

[Modified Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y662u181/)

Comment: It doesn't work. Just make a search with some random letters and you will see that the "No matching records found" row is still selectable.

Comment: sorry about that. had not considered that scenario. from the api documentation what i found was adding the two resources for select there is not additional logic required. just an option to enable select. i.e 'select:true'. here is the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vje9e2sL/ . please check resources in the fiddle for required css and js files.

Comment: the on 'select' is not mandatory. its just if you want to do additional processing. so please ignore if not required.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, but I need to do more things in the select event, so I need to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

inside your click method, add before everything

```
if($('#exampleTable tbody tr td').length == 1){
      return;
    }
```

Comment: This will disable the selection always there is only one row, even when the row is a valid record.

Comment: so check with `td` (I've updated) because your 'no message' row just have one `td` (assuming that your datatable data has more than one `td`) should work as expected